# How to calculate checksum in React Native and Node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native, aws-lambda, react-native-fs

I'm uploading an image file from React Native to AWS Lambda (Node 10.x) and want to verify the hash of the file I've sent matches the file received. To do this I'm using hashing in React Native and again in Lambda, but the hashes never match. Here are the relevant bits of code I've tried.

React Native

```
import RNFS from "react-native-fs";
const contentChecksum = await RNFS.hash(post.contentUrl, "md5");
```

Lambda (Node)

```
import AWS from "aws-sdk";
const crypto = require("crypto");
const s3 = new AWS.S3();

const data = await s3
    .getObject({
      Bucket: file.bucket,
      Key: file.key
    })
    .promise();
const contentChecksum = crypto
    .createHash("md5")
    .update(data.Body)
    .digest("hex");
```

These checksums never match. I've tried using `base64` encoding in Node (`data.Body.toString("base64")`) and also `sha256`. What is the trick to calculating the checksum so they match in React Native and Node?

Edit: Here are the results from a recent test.

`post.contentUrl`: `file:///Users/xxxxxxx/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/2F2F4FD3-574E-40D7-BE6B-7080E926E70A/data/Containers/Data/Application/65A3FF67-98B2-444D-B75D-3717C1274FBC/Library/Caches/Camera/FDCD8F90-D24F-4E64-851A-96AB388C4B59.jpg`

(the file is local on an iPhone)

`contentChecksum` from React Native: 48aa5cdb30f01719a2b12d481dc22f04

`contentChecksum` from Node (Lambda): 7b30b61a55d2c39707082293c625fc10

`data.Body` is a `Buffer`.

I also note that the eTag attribute on the S3 object matches the md5 checksum I'm calculating in Node. Since eTag is *usually* the md5 hash of the file, this tells me that I'm likely calculating the hash incorrectly in React Native, but I'm not sure how. I'm using the [hash](https://github.com/itinance/react-native-fs#hashfilepath-string-algorithm-string-promisestring) function from the react-native-fs package.

Comment: What do the outputs look like and what is the value of `post.contentUrl` and `data.Body`?

Comment: @tbking I've added more info in the question.

Comment: Looks like an encoding issue. Try `data.Body.toString()` in node.

Comment: That didn't seem to help.

Comment: access the file object in react-native and take the hash of it, and similar on lambda, use the file content and take hash of the content again, that should be the logic.

Comment: Isn't that what I'm doing in the code? `RNFS.hash()` calculates the hash of the file in react-native, and `crypto.createHash("md5").update(data.Body).digest("hex")` does the same in lambda. Can you provide an example of what you mean?

Comment: Can you generate th MD5 using an external program to see if at least one of the 2 output is right.  In Win10: CertUtil -hashfile image.jpg MD5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the same code on *React* and *AWS Lambda*, that is **Node.js**.

So in your *React.js* application you could use the following code:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import crypto from 'crypto';

var key = 'YOUR_KEY';

export default class Test extends React.Component {

    render() {
        var hash = crypto.createHash('md5').update(key).digest('hex');
        return (
            <div>
                {hash}
            </div>
        )
    }

}
```

And the variable `hash` have to contains the same value you get on AWS.

In order to run you have to install the crypto library:

```
npm i --save react-native-crypto
```

Change the variable YOUR_KEY, then run the application:

```
npm start
```

And in the browser you should get:

```
4b751fef5e9660e3943173fd3e6c4224
```

Comment: What is the npm repository for the crypto package? In node it is built in but needs to be installed from somewhere in React.

Comment: @Fook I've updated my answer, please take a look. Bye.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the *crypto* module.

To get a list of all available hash algorithms, you can use `crypto.getHashes()`.

Here is a Nodejs example:

```
var crypto = require('crypto')

crypto.getHashes() // [ 'dsa', 'dsa-sha', ..., 'md5', ... ]
```

Here is a helper method for generating checksum value from string input:

```
var crypto = require('crypto')

function checksum(str, algorithm, encoding) {
  return crypto
    .createHash(algorithm || 'md5')
    .update(str, 'utf8')
    .digest(encoding || 'hex')
}

checksum('This is my test text'); 
checksum('This is my test text', 'sha1');
```